# Create a basic Socket.IO Websocket server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am writing a websocket server with `socket.io` but don't know why is not working.

**This works:**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8100});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

    console.log('New connection!');

    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Client connection closed!');
    });

    ws.on('message', function(message) {

    });

});
```

**This runs, but my client is not able to connect:**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8100);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New Connection');
});
```

*Source: Book Professional Node.js*

The client is a Javascript basic web browser client that works with any server so please disregard client side issues.

Comment: `The client is a Javascript basic web browser client that works with any server` Ah, if life was that easy. Socket.io provides its own client. I don't remember details now but it is possible that the `connection` event is fired not at the moment of conenction but when the client sends some data. That would be done in order to unify the event between different pushing strategies.

Comment: If I can't use my own websocket client with socket.io, then this library is absolutely obsolete for my purpose.

Comment: Well that's up to you. Anyway you've asked the question, so my question to you is: did you try it with the client socket.io provides? I might be wrong and the issue may lay somewhere else.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the transports to websocket only, since socket.io has fallbacks.

Comment: @Ben how do I do that ? I didn't get your point sorry

Comment: @JackM. `socket.io` is _not_ a WebSocket server.  It is a higher level protocol built on a combination of http and WebSockets, utilizing multiple transports (one of which is WebSockets).  You have to use a `socket.io` client (they exist for many platforms, as it is a well-documented protocol).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the transports explicitly to websocket only, since socket.io has fallback options for long-polling and flash sockets.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8100, {transports: ['websocket']})

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New Connection');
});
```

Comment: I feel that the problem is the code really because when my client tries to connect to a wrong port number, you can feel it holding for a second. If you try to connect to the right port 8100, it immediately get Disconnected - Status 3 (without status 1)

Comment: Is there any reason not to use WS?

Comment: I don't know how to scale (multiple server instances) with WS and not sure if it works well behind proxy/load balancer

Comment: I see. Scaling is far easier with socket.io as you can just plug it into redis. What's the reason for not using the socket.io client?

Comment: The client is a Windows/Mac application, not a webpage.

Comment: You might want to change your question then, since you've stated that it's a Javascript client.